# Using Window 10 new bash capability, running into problems installing postgresql

Tags: apt, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying out Windows 10 new bash capability and I've run into some problems trying to install Postgresql. I've tried apt-get update, apt-get upgrade init-system-helpers, apt-get autoremove and still get the same error. I'm fairly new to the command line so please bear with me. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
bill@ME-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Me$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
[sudo] password for bill:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-common : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
bill@ME-PC:/mnt/c/Users/Me$
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently (October 2017), WSL runs Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and the installation works OK.

---

- To check which version of Ubuntu you are running, you can run the following command

  ```
  $ lsb-release -d
  ```
- If you have an older version, you can upgrade the distribution using `do-release-upgrade`

  ```
  $ sudo do-release-upgrade
  ```
- As an alternative, you can uninstall the WSL from your computer and download the new [Ubuntu from the Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6). You can uninstall the WSL running the following command in Windows

  ```
  C:\> lxrun /uninstall /full /y
  ```

  And reinstall, using the same `lxrun`

  ```
  C:\> lxrun /install
  ```